# Translate the term "Idoneità concorsuale" from Italian to English

Tags: american-english, italian

I am trying to translate the term "Idoneità concorsuale" or "Idoneità concorso pubblico" from Italian to American English. In Italy, in many competitions related to public administration, even if you do not win you can enter a kind of ranking list (valid 3 years by law) from which you can be called under certain circumstances and be hired.

for example:

Eligibility for the competition for Professional XXXX III level at the YYYY ZZZZ WWWW (YZW), Institute for MMM (3M), ranking list dated yyyy/mm/dd, Notice No. 368.35

where ranking list is "graduatoria" e Notice is "Bando" (del concorso).

Comment: “Eligibility  for competition rankings” may convey the concept.

Comment: Thanks. I Update my post. What do you think? thanks again

Comment: I doubt you'll find a perfect translation; English-speaking countries don't (to my knowledge) have such systems, so there's been no need to develop a term for it.

Comment: Something like "preselected" might work, though.

Comment: This sounds similar to a "wait list"

Comment: Or "standby list". "Alternate" (noun) is used for people who don't quite get onto school sports teams and similar, but never heard it in this context.

Comment: @alphabet . I think you have a similar procedure  in the States as far as far  as the  Congress   or Senate are concerned. When a member, for any reason, is no longer available, their place is taken by the next in line.

Comment: I presume that only the candidates whose scores are above some threshold get to be on the list. If so, one **might** perhaps be able to say that the candidate **passed the state examination** for . . . , but as has already been pointed out no English expression is going to work perfectly, as most English speakers will be unfamiliar with this way of certifying and hiring public servants. You may be able to get a more helpful answer by consulting bilingual colleagues in the relevant professional field.

Comment: Google suggests the simple translation is 'eligibility for competition' but two things: in English, that would be a rather strange thing. Further, while the Question title seems clear, the exposition makes it seem almost meaningless…

Answer (score 0):

Briefly - in medicine you may be ***"provisionally registered"***. This allows you to complete a UK approved F1 programme, which is the first year of a two-year  training programme to fully register you as a doctor. The provisional registration is only valid for a little over three years.

> [General Medical Council](https://www.gmc-uk.org/registration-and-licensing/join-the-register/provisional-registration/purpose-and-limitations-of-provisional-registrations)

There are similar arrangements for pharmacists:

> [General Pharmaceutical Council](https://www.pharmacyregulation.org/registers/provisional-registration-pharmacists)

I know of no similar British arrangements for general public administration or the civil service.